# Fitnesse: No ErrorLogs generated in command line/linux environment

Tags: fitnesse

Running Fitnesse in Linux using a command line such as:
java -jar fitnesse.jar -c "TestName?test&format=text"

However, the system.out, which shows up in ErrorLogs in a PC environment does not get created.

Is there a switch to turn this on?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation for the command line options:
http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.QuickReferenceGuide#FitNesseCommandLINE

It looks like there's a -l option to specify where the logs should be created.

Comment: Isn't the -l option just for an access log?

From the Fitnesse manual [link](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.LogFiles):

_If File logging is turned on (with the -l command line argument) then FitNesse will record all accesses in log files_

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying **-l /tmp/log.out** just to make sure there are no permissions issues.

Comment: You should provide a directory, not a file. When I enable logging with `-l /tmp` the file `fitnesse20120730101234.log' gets created in /tmp